# Quasar routing not working with vueRouterMode hash

Tags: vue.js, routes, quasar-framework

I have a very simple routing, my routes.ts is below. When I use vueRouterMode: 'history' in quasar.config.js, it works as intended. However, when I use vueRouterMode: 'hash', as it was by default, it doesn't. All the url load Home.vue as if url was '/', and even wrong urls aren't catched by the catchAll. How are you supposed to use vueRouterMode: 'hash' correctly?

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('pages/Home.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'caisse',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: () => import('pages/CaisseListe.vue')
          },
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: () => import('pages/CaisseDetail.vue')
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

Comment: Please include relevant code which would be your configuration of `quasar.config.js`, and while it should be mostly default it'd be prudent to confirm how the router is created in `/router/index.ts`.  Also, can you give some more details regarding the issue.  Is the issue in dev or prod?  are you loading URLs directly or using in-app site navigation links?  What are some examples of URLs/pages you're trying to load and what is actual vs expected result of the URL that ends up loading?